# DocstringParsingError when using natspec with internal or private functions

Tags: truffle, natspec

Ethereum's [natspec](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Natural-Specification-Format) mentions:

> You are welcome to use similar comments for your internal and private functions, but those will not be parsed.

However, when documenting internal functions, I get errors like the following:

```
DocstringParsingError: Documented parameter "amount" not found in the parameter list of the function.
```

I'm using Truffle to run tests. It appears it's attempting to parse the natspec for internal functions when it should be skipping them.

Is there a way to disable this?

So far I'm getting away by using regular comments (`//`) for internal functions.

Comment: I have the same error. Did you find a solution?